# Add FIRST Attachement (picture) to a report in access

Tags: ms-access

I have a table [List_Models] which has 3 fields

- PK - Model_ID (num)
- Model_Name (txt)
- Picture (attachment)

A certain model has plenty of colour combinations (one has 52) and so 52 pictures attached.

On my report, however, I simply want to attach first (or any) of those pictures, as long as it is a correct model.

Basically no matter colour combination, simply show a picture so it is easier to visualise the model itself.

How do I go about this in the easiest way?

I have made a query to fetch first picture from the attachment (ie. 2 columns, Model_ID, Picture.FileData). Here is the syntax:

```
SELECT Zoznam_Modelov.Model_ID, Zoznam_Modelov.Picture.FileData
FROM (SELECT Zoznam_Modelov.Model_ID, Max(Zoznam_Modelov.Picture) AS MaxzPicture FROM Zoznam_Modelov WHERE (((Zoznam_Modelov.model_id) Is Not Null)) GROUP BY Zoznam_Modelov.Model_ID)  AS U_Pic 
INNER JOIN Zoznam_Modelov ON U_Pic.Model_ID = Zoznam_Modelov.Model_ID
WHERE (((Zoznam_Modelov.Picture.FileName)=U_Pic.[MaxzPicture]));
```

Then I tried attaching the FileData to the report in this way:

- Make Attachment field in Form
- Set Control Source as:

  ```
  =DLookUp("Zoznam_Modelov.Picture.FileData";"qryUnique_Pictures_Data";"Model_ID = " & [Model_ID])
  ```

However, it remains blank.

Comment: what have you tried so far? Have you tried a DLookup?  or a query with "TOP 1"? or maybe a function to pull a random attachment?

Comment: I have made a query which fetchs first attachment and then I tried to add that attachment to the form, however, it does not work. My query looks like this: (updated question).

Comment: try putting vba in your onload event of the detail section. me.MyImageControl.picture = DLookUp("Zoznam_Modelov.Picture.FileData";"qryUnique_Pictures_Data";"Model_ID = " & [Model_ID])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I go about this in the easiest way?

Just open the report in Design View, then drag and drop the Attachment field onto the report. That will add an Attachment control that is bound to the Attachment field. The default settings will display the first attachment (picture) on the report like this:

[image: HeyNow.png]

Comment: I cannot "drag and drop" the field. When I drag the "Attachment field" from my table over to "Report", the report doesn't get focus (doesnt go to frong screen) in order to "drop" it there.

Comment: I have solved it by creating a new report solely for pictures (as you said, it simply shows the first picture, which is very neat) and then I added it as  subReport to my mainReport. Thanks for help!